# Ata Chonantanu after havdala

Tags: maariv, havdalah

Should one say ata chonantanu if they have already heard havdala at home?

I don't know that there is a problem with it necessarily (it is not its own bracha, which is the point after all) but should it be said?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Talmud asks this question on [Brachot 33a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=33&format=pdf) and concludes that one still says Attah Chonantanu in Shemone Esrei even if he already recited Havdala on a cup of wine, because the Havdalah in Shemone Esrei was the original and therefore primary form of Havdala enacted. This ruling is brought in the [Tur OC 294](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&pgnum=484) and cited in the [Mishnah Berurah there :1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14171&pgnum=140).