# Forgot atah chonantanu in maariv, but have to say tashlumin

Tags: halacha, mistakes, havdalah, motzei-shabbos, tashlumin

If someone doesn't daven *shemoneh esrei* for certain reasons, he is able to make it up by davening two *shemoneh esrei*s at the next davening ('*tashlumin*). The second one is the exact same as the first, except in the case of tashlumin motzei Shabbat,  where *atah chonantanu* is not said the second time.

In an ordinary case, if someone forgets *atah chonantanu*, they don't repeat shemoneh esrei, because they can just say havdalah later.

So, here, what if someone forgets mincha Shabbat afternoon and has to say *tashlumin* at maariv. Then, they forgot *atah chonantanu* in the first (maariv) *shemoneh esrei*. Should they say it in the *tashlumin* (mincha) *shemoneh esrei*, even though it wouldn't normally be said then?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35796/759

Comment: @DoubleAA not a dupe?

Comment: @Matt No, it's not. In that question, maariv was never said. Here, there's no tashlumin for maariv; it's for mincha.

Answer (score 6):

The basic rule by *tashlumin* is that for all make-up prayers, the first prayer is the current one and the make-up is said afterwards.  If this order is switched, the first prayer is invalid (S.A. O.C. 108:1-2).

108:2

> טעה ולא התפלל מנחה מתפלל ערבית שתים הראשונה ערבית והשניה לתשלומין.

108:1

> ואם היפך לא יצא ידי תפלה שהיא תשלומין וצריך לחזור ולהתפלל אותה וכן הדין בכל מקום שצריך להתפלל תפלה לתשלומין

*Atta chonantanu* is meant to be said in the first shemoneh esrei, which is the maariv shemoneh esrei. When someone doesn't say *atta chonantanu* altogether, they would not need to repeat in order to say it.  However, if one says *atta chonantanu* in the second shemoneh esrei, they are showing that their second shemoneh esrei was their maariv, in which case they davened their make-up mincha before the current maariv, and their mincha is invalid .  Therefore, you should not say *atta chonantanu* in the second shemoneh esrei (O.C. 108:10 and M.B. 29).

S.A. 108:10

> בדיל בראשונה ואינו מבדיל בשניה ואם לא הבדיל בראשונה והבדיל בשניה שניה עלתה לו ראשונה לא עלתה לו

[However, if you explicitly had in mind that the first was for Maariv and the second was the mincha make-up, and did not switch the order, you do not need to repeat shemoneh esrei and both count (M.B ibid).]

Comment: Maybe you should say _atta chonantanu_ in the second one and explicitly have in mind that the first is for Maariv and the second is the mincha make-up?